# speed up ghost cleanup

Tags: sql-server, delete

In SQL Server I have a table that is filled often and also gets deleted often.
Because several threads write and erase data from that table I cannot even truncate it because there is always someone accessing it.

Thats why the threads do "delete from" statements.

As result I now have a table that has 6 TB (terabyte) of reserved space and 0 rows.
The reserved space goes down slowly implying the ghost cleanup works.
I know I can rebuild the table or truncate it, but I wonder if there is a solution that I can use to speed up deletion during runtime? Is there a possibility to speed up ghost cleaner somehow?

Comment: Paul's [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/23718) at serverfault will help you.

Comment: Can you rebuild online (Enterprise Edition)? Then it doesn't matter how long it takes because it's not blocking anyone from accessing. You could also drop/re-create the table in a transaction whenever it's empty, which would take it offline for a tiny blip.

Comment: Is the table a heap?  Heaps don't release space after a delete (although they may reuse it).  If it has 0 rows, you could drop the table and put it back in with an appropriate clustered index.